# How can I create a live user count on my firebase and flutter app?

Tags: android, ios, firebase, flutter, firebase-analytics

I want to include a text box on my app that displays how many users are currently on the app (concurrent users). I'm using Firebase and flutter and I'm wondering if anyone has any suggestions. I know firebase reports the amount of live users for analytics, but is there a way to take that data and show it to the users?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a combination of a `presence` state watcher like [here](https://medium.com/flutter-community/managing-user-presence-in-cloud-firestore-using-flutter-7cad50a5e3db) for each user and save the presence state on the database AND a simple cloud function that listens to the changes and increments or decrements the total counter.